# How can I make a card element to be a link in Boomla?

Tags: links

I have a card element in Boomla UIKit, and I want it to become a clickable link that leads to another site (and also set `target=_blank` possibly).

I've searched for the available elements, but couldn't find a link element under Navigation. The closest was Anchor, but it seems to be only a point to jump to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic "link" element at the moment that works as a container for other elements.

You would need to write custom code for that. For example, a simple wrapper could look like this:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">
    <?== f.query('elems/*').inline() ?>
</a>
```

**Edit**: The problem is that a generic link element doesn't compose well with other elements. Sure, it works to place an image in it, but even placing a text element in it will look odd. (Just tried, the text was gray having a colored underline.) Also, what shall happen if you place a slideshow in it? A contact form? So that's something that would need more consideration on what should be allowed to go in it, and the list would be pretty limiting. If you want to create a custom looking card, I recommend writing some custom HTML code for that.